# Netty Unable to receive whole packet

Tags: java, tcp, server, byte, netty

It seems that I can't figure out, why am I getting first packet splitted, and the rest of the packets I receive as one.

The first received thing is IMEI (17 bytes), the netty server sends back 01 respond and starts sending the packets, which I respond to them with another respond.

But why do I keep getting first packet in two parts ? While others are being send as one (which is ok). It always receives up to 1024 bytes and then the rest of 251 bytes . The whole package is up to 1275 bytes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking there is not guarantee if a packet is split or not when using TCP. So you can not make any assumptions on this.

That said what you see may be the result of using `AdaptiveRecvByteBufAllocator` (which is the default) as it starts with small allocation sizes and then increase these if needed.

You could use a different `RecvByteBufAllocator` if you want to change the behaviour. But again this is nothing you can depend on.

Comment: Thank you good sir, adding `.childOption(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, new AdaptiveRecvByteBufAllocator(1024,16*1024,1024*1024))` to serverboostrap  did the trick. Not sure what it does, but it works with my packets now.